# Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here? [React hooks]

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use the **useDebounce** hook in the *handleChange* function. But I am getting the following error

**React Hook "useDebounce" is called in function "handleChange" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. (react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)**

The code is as follows

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function useDebounce(value, delay) {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value)

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => setDebouncedValue(value), delay || 500)

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer)
    }
  }, [value, delay])

  return debouncedValue
}

const handleChange = (e) => {
  let debouncedValue = useDebounce(e.target.value, 500);
  console.log('debouncedValue', debouncedValue);
}

export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={(e) => {handleChange(e)}} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Request if someone can shed some light as to what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Just FYI, it's not helpful to post screenshots of errors/code - as they are not searchable.

Comment: @dwjohnston Sure, replaced the screenshot with text. Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the error message? I don't think it could be much more clear. You can only call hooks from a components render function directly.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Like the error states, it's invalid to call React hooks in callbacks.

See [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

- Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.
- Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.

## Solution

It seems like you are really wanting to debounce the `handleChange` callback handler.

Import a debouncing utility or create your own simple `debounce` higher order function.

Example:

```
const debounce = (fn, delay) => {
  let timerId;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), delay);
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(value);

  const handleChange = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  const debouncedHandler = debounce(handleChange, 500);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={debouncedHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooks in React can only be called from React components or from other hooks.
React seems to validate hooks/components via their name scheme.
I.E. - hooks start with "use", components start with an uppercase letter.

Check out React's [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions) section regarding this.

So what's heppening here is that you are trying to use your custom `useDebounce` hook in a regular function.
Which would be the equivalent of trying to use `useState` or `useEffect` outside of a React component, and will produce the same error.

The solution is to either change the naming schemes or the structure of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function useDebounce(value, delay) {
    const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => setDebouncedValue(value), delay || 500);

        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        };
    }, [value, delay]);

    return debouncedValue;
}

export default function App() {
    const [term, setTerm] = React.useState('');
    const debouncedValue = useDebounce(term, 500);
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setTerm(e.target.value);
        console.log('debouncedValue', debouncedValue);
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search"
                onChange={(e) => {
                    handleChange(e);
                }}
            />
            {debouncedValue}
        </div>
    );
}
```